# Multiple begin end statement in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Do different begin end statements executed concurrently in verilog?

Here's the code:

`//Sample test values to run simulation (module jkflop_top continues)
    initial begin

        j=0; k=0; rst=1;
        #4
        j=1; k=1; rst=0;
        #50
        j=0; k=1; rst=0;
        #20
        j=1; k=1; rst=0;
    end
    //Carry out simulation for 100 units of time
    initial begin
        #100
        $finish;
    end
    endmodule`

What the code does is it provides sample input for a j-k flip flop. As the second begin should be finished after 100 units delay from starting of the program if they are concurrent, will the total program run for 100 time units only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different **initial** statements operate concurrently.This has nothing to do with begin/end.

The begin/end only 'group' all the code with one initial.

Here we have two begin/end statements. They do not operate concurrently, they operate sequentially.

```
   for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
   begin
   ... // some code
   end
   for (j=0; j<8; j=j+1)
   begin
   ... // some more code
   end
```

Here we have two initial statement, without begin/end. They operate concurrently.

```
initial
   #50 reset = 1'b0;

initial
   #100 clk= 1'b1;
```